# How to let threads access a resource concurrently except when a master operation is called?

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency

I have a situation with many threads repeatedly executing the same delegate (C#/.NET 4.5).

Each call of the delegate takes a record and inserts it into a central data structure. The central data structure is thread-safe for concurrent inserts.

Once the central data structure reaches a certain size it needs to be flushed to an external data store. This process is *not* thread safe, and inserts need to be suspended while this process is going on.

How can I allow the inserts to occur in parallel but block them when the flush occurs (blocking the flush until any active inserts finish as well)? Locking on the central data structure would eliminate the required parallelism on the inserts.

**Broken** code example:

```
    private static readonly int MAX_ITEMS = 10;
    private volatile int isFlushingToCentralDataStore = 0;
    DataStore centralDataStructure = new DataStore();

    // Prevent multiple threads from triggering an external DB access at once
    private volatile int isFlushCheckGoingOn = 0;
    private SemaphoreSlim externalAccessControl = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

    /*Code that calls processRecord on many different lines on many
    different threads at once*/

    private void processRecord(string line)
    {
        Record rec = processLine(line); // Expensive

        if (1 == isFlushCheckGoingOn)
        {
            externalAccessControl.Wait();
            centralDataStructure.insertRecord(rec);
            externalAccessControl.Release();
        }
        else // Fast concurrent path
        {
            //PROBLEM: Nothing preventing this from starting if isFlushCheckGoingOn changed very recently
            centralDataStructure.insertRecord(rec); // Safe for multiple threads to do at once (except flushToExternalDataStore)
        }

        // If another thread is executing this block we skip it, but if no one is we do it
        if (0 == Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref isFlushCheckGoingOn, 1, 0))
        {
            if (centralDataStructure.Size > MAX_ITEMS) // Ok if we go slightly over MAX_ITEMS
            {
                externalAccessControl.Wait();
                centralDataStructure.flushToExternalDataStore();
                externalAccessControl.Release();
            }
            Interlocked.MemoryBarrier();
            isFlushCheckGoingOn = 0;
        }
```

What I have so far covers most of the edge cases, but I can't quite pin down a way to be able to get the needed parallelism on inserts while also being able to ensure that no inserts are happening while the flush is going on.

What's the best way to do this kind of synchronization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the built in type [`ReaderWriterLockSlim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim(v=vs.110).aspx). For your inserts you would take a read lock, for the flush you would take a write lock.

During the read lock it will allow unlimited reads, when you try to take the write lock it will stop all new reads and once all the reads finish it will do the single flush operation.

```
private static readonly int MAX_ITEMS = 10;
DataStore centralDataStructure = new DataStore();

private ReaderWriterLockSlim readerWriterLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

/*Code that calls processRecord on many different lines on many
different threads at once*/

private void processRecord(string line)
{
    Record rec = processLine(line); // Expensive

    //Allows unlimited concurrent readers and a single upgradeable reader.
    readerWriterLock.EnterReadLock()
    try
    {
        centralDataStructure.insertRecord(rec);
    }
    finally
    {
        readerWriterLock.ExitReadLock()
    }

    //Allows other readers, blocks writers and other upgradeable readers.
    //If it can't take the lock it skips the rest of the code.
    var lockTaken = readerWriterLock.TryEnterUpgradeableReadLock(0)
    if(lockTaken)
    {
        try
        {
            if (centralDataStructure.Size > MAX_ITEMS) // Ok if we go slightly over MAX_ITEMS
            {
                //Blocks new readers and other writers. Waits for current readers to finsh before unblocking.
                readerWriterLock.EnterWriteLock();
                try
                {
                    centralDataStructure.flushToExternalDataStore();
                }
                finally
                {
                    //Allow readers again.
                    readerWriterLock.ExitWriteLock();
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
             //Allow writers and upgradeable readers again.
             readerWriterLock.ExitUpgradeableReadLock()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think ReaderWriterLockSlim is exactly what I'm looking for. As implemented every thread will block every execution for the upgradable lock to check if size is big enough to warrant a flush, but I think this can be avoided by using the Interlocked CompareExchange trick.

Comment: Actually TryEnterUpgradeableReadLock(0) looks like it handles this for me; no need to manually do CompareExchange.

Comment: @Techrocket9 good idea, I updated the answer with that change.